# How to return JWT Auth decrypted Token in web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("~/decrypt/token")]
public string TestJwtSecurityTokenHandler([FromBody] string token)
{
    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(token);
}
```

This is my sample post method to decode the Token getting from From Body. I need to decode this and return a decoded value.

Comment: JWT aren't *encrypted* so they can't be *decrypted*.  [JWT are encoded](https://jwt.io/introduction), so you should just be able to decode it via `Convert.FromBase64String(token)`.

Comment: yeah but how will I return in above code?

Comment: If you need to return a string then you can use `return Ok(string)` and change your return type to an IActionResult.

Comment: [HttpPost]
        [Route("~/decrypt/token")]
        public string TestJwtSecurityTokenHandler([FromBody] string token)
        {
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(token);

            return Ok (jsonToken);
           
        } not working :/

Answer (score 0):

Like Erik Philips said you'll have to change the return type into an IActionResult.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("~/decrypt/token")]
public ActionResult<string> TestJwtSecurityTokenHandler([FromBody] string token) 
{
    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(token);

    return jsonToken;
}
```